# Card game about collecting farms

Tags: identify-this-game

The game involves collecting farms or ranches, cattle or sheep, jackaroo or something along those lines.  I played it in the 90's with an older couple, that's not to say it was from the 90's though. I'm pretty sure it was an Australian company that produced it.

I thought it was called "Squatter", but that's the board game not a card game.

Comment: You question doesn't have much detail at the moment so might get closed for lack of detail.  You can help by give more detail.  Was this played with a standard deck of cards or one produced for the game?   Were you collecting cards or some other tokens?  Did the game have a board?  Do you remember what you did on a turn or how you win?   The more details you can recall the more likely someone is to recognise the game you want to find.

Comment: Your description certainly reminds me of Squatter, which is like Monopoly but with farms, pasture improvements and sheep, instead of streets and houses. As in Monopoly, there are cards involved even though it is primarily a board game—are you positive you aren’t misremembering the role of the cards in the game?